# setInterval and clearInterval javascript not working as needed

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

I have the following code partially working. I am newbie in javascript so please don't blame me if my approach is not the best.

```
window.url_var = "status.htm";
window.elem = "#e1";

function menu_item(){
$(window.elem).click(function (event)
{ 
    $("#divTestArea1").load(window.url_var);
});
}

$("#e1").click(function (event)
{ 
event.preventDefault(); 
window.url_var = "demo2.txt";
window.elem = "#e1";
$("#divTestArea1").load(window.url_var);
auto_refresh = setInterval(menu_item(), 5000);  
});


$("#e2").click(function (event)
{ 
event.preventDefault(); 
window.url_var = "status.htm";
window.elem = "#e2";
$("#divTestArea1").load(window.url_var);
auto_refresh = setInterval(menu_item(), 5000);  
});

$("#e3").click(function (event)
{ 
event.preventDefault(); 
window.url_var = "form.htm";
window.elem = "#e3";
clearInterval(auto_refresh);
$("#divTestArea1").load(window.url_var);
});


jQuery(document).ready(function() {
$("#divTestArea1").load(window.url_var);
auto_refresh = setInterval(menu_item(), 5000);  
});
```

Whenever I click elements e1 and e2,  the setInterval works as expected and as soon as I click element e3, the element cease to be reloaded.

That's the behavior I want so far. But I also wants to start the setinterval again if e1 or e2 get's again clicked.

the last is what it's not working on the above code.

I will appreciate if you could point me in the right direction.

---

I have come to this code after seeing some of the answers to my original question (thanks to everyone). To clarify my original idea, I need to update some items on my web page on a regular basics but the content can be change with some menu and also some of the contents like a form should not be updated.

```
window.url_var = "demo2.txt";
var     auto_refresh = null;

function setRefresh() {
    var self = this;
    this.bar = function() {
      if(window.url_var != ""){ 
    $("#divTestArea1").load(window.url_var);
            auto_refresh = setTimeout(function() { self.bar(); }, 5000);
        }
    }
    this.bar();
}

$("#e1").click(function (event)
{ 
    event.preventDefault(); 
    window.url_var = "demo2.txt";
    setRefresh();
});  


$("#e2").click(function (event)
{ 
    event.preventDefault(); 
    window.url_var = "status.htm";
    setRefresh();
});  

$("#e3").click(function (event)
{ 
    event.preventDefault(); 
    window.url_var = "form.htm";
    $("#divTestArea1").load(window.url_var);
    window.url_var = "";
});


$(document).ready(function() {
    setRefresh();
});
```

Comment: remove setInterval(menu_item(), 5000); and add setInterval(menu_item, 5000); for all the setInterval/setTimeout

Answer (score 1):

Try using 2 different variables and clearing all if needed. This is: auto_refresh1 and auto_refresh2. Each time you call setinterval, it creates a new timer with a new id. You are overwriting auto_refresh variable and the timer before that will still fire.

Or you can store the setinterval in a hash object and run through and clear them all.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unclear as to what exactly it is that you're trying to do here. Nevertheless, I've rewritten your code a bit to make some improvements (and fix one glaring bug in your code involving the `setInterval` calls).

```
var url_var = "status.htm",
    elem = "#e1",
    $destination = $("#divTestArea1"),
    auto_refresh;

function menu_item() {
    $(elem).bind("click", function (e) {
        $destination.load(url_var);
    });
}

function load() {
    $destination.load(url_var);
}

function set(url, id) {
    url_var = url;
    elem = id;
}

function setRefresh() {
    return setInterval(menu_item, 5000);
}

function handleClick(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    set(e.data.url, e.data.id);
    load();
    auto_refresh = setRefresh();
}

$("#e1").on("click", {
    url: "demo2.txt",
    id: "#e1"
}, handleClick);

$("#e2").on("click", {
    url: "status.htm",
    id: "#e2"
}, handleClick);

$("#e3").on("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    set("form.htm", "#e3");
    clearInterval(auto_refresh);
    load();
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    load();
    auto_refresh = setRefresh();
});
```

I'm guessing that maybe those `setInterval` calls should actually be `setTimeout` calls? Why would you want to bind a "click" event handler over and over again?

**EDIT #1:** Switched to jQuery's currently preferred `on` method from the `bind` method, included use of event data parameter to further abstract event handling code.

Comment: Just because i am so newbie to javascript it's maybe the answer. After your response I realize that I was binding the click to the event handler over and over. Thank you for everything.